# How and what are unit test case for data class using mockito or hamcrest in kotlin

Tags: android, mockito, hamcrest

```
data class User(val name : String?, val age : Int?)
```

This is my data class i want write  unit test case so that it should give 100 percent coverage also i want to write all test case for null safety  so that if  variable can accept null value also please suggest me what are the test case  how so write test case using mockito or hamcrest .

Comment: If this class had an implementation, it would make sense, but this class seems to not have more than the default implementation that kotlin generates during build

Comment: @LenaBru could you please more explanation  my understanding you mean data class  value we are using in repo , use class and view model then also we do not  need to test  ?

Comment: if you have another class that uses this class, and you want to test that, there would be some tests. Could you post the class that uses this data class so i can give an example?

Comment: @LenaBru. Thanks for good idea  https://github.com/anilthakur/MyWeatherApp please check this git code implemented by me i want  write test of model and view model we are using its with null safety

Comment: can you please be more specific, which class names you are referring to ?

Comment: I want to test WeeatherForecst entities  classes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208305/discussion-between-lena-bru-and-marsh).